# What is the shortcut key to jump to the Windows Search search box in Explorer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-search

Is there a shortcut key to jump to the windows search box in Windows 10 when running Explorer.exe?

Comment: CTRL+F works for me. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Windows Explorer window, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

This will give focus to the search box and you can begin typing.